# GoogleMaps API V3: Mouse hot spot area of marker is shifted

Tags: marker, area

I'm trying to create a googlemap which contains a marker with an individual image instead of the standard google pin. The image is a 14 by 14 pixel GIF. By clicking on the image, a small information window shall appear.

Both the GIF and the HTML file are stored in a local directory.

My code works fine, except one thing: The "hot spot" area, that is clickable with the mouse, isn't lying on the GIF itself. Instead, it is a square that is located just left above the GIF - the lower right corner of the hot spot area is at the upper left corner of the GIF. So if I want the infowindow to appear, I have to click left above the GIF, not on the GIF.

I haven't seen this effect on my V2-map. I already was fooling around with the parameters size, origin and anchor of the image object, but to no avail. The anchor parameter just shifts the location of the image, but it also shifts the clickable area. The size parameter has only an effect if it is smaller than the GIF itself; then it cuts the edges of the GIF. Also the origin parameter lets the GIF just look funny.

Any ideas that might help? Here's the code I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>GMaps V3</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
*  { FONT-FAMILY: Arial,sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 12px; margin: 0.2em; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&key=" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[
    function load() {

      var center_of_map = new google.maps.LatLng(50.0, 11.0);
      var marker_pos = new google.maps.LatLng(50.03, 10.98);
      var mapOptions = { zoom: 10, center: center_of_map };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

      var image = {
        url: 'bridge.gif',
        size: new google.maps.Size(14, 14),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
      }

      var markerProperties = {
            map: map,
            title: "Click me!",
            icon: image,
            position: marker_pos
          };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerProperties);

      var myInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        { content: "This is an information window" }
      );

      google.maps.event.addListener(
        marker, 'click', function() {
            myInfo.open(map, marker);
         }
      );

    } //load
        //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load()">
    <table border="1">
      <tr><td><b>This is our map</b></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div></td><tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that it has something to do with the included style. If I comment out the lines, the effect is no longer visible and everything is as it should be. Funny!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The fix in my case was to add a class to the body as such:

```
body.no-zoom {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

However, in my case the map was a direct child div node of the body.

```
<body class="no-zoom">
    <div id="map-canvas">
    </div>
</body>
```